# Can't get Drush to function

Tags: drush

I have a local site but drush doesn't seem to be functioning correctly:

$drush status=

```
PHP executable         :  /usr/local/bin/php                                      
PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini                          
PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                                  
Drush script           :  /Users/myuser/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php           
Drush version          :  8.1.5                                                   
Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                                    
Drush configuration    :                                                          
Drush alias files      :  /Users/myuser/.drush/sitename.aliases.drushrc.php
```

It's not listing anything about the drupal site, so I can't run any drush commands on the local.

Does anyone know how to set this up correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I'm reporting back to provide my solution.

The site itself was Drupal v 7.51. As you can see, I was using Drush v. 8.1.5.

Reverting back to 7 corrected the issue and was done fairly easily following the modules unraveled tutorial here: https://modulesunraveled.com/blog/install-drush-7-and-8-and-automatically-switch-versions-based-project.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Drush 8.1.5 should work just fine with Drupal 7. There shouldn't be a need to revert back to drush-7 just for that.

Typically if you don't get back any Drupal information from `status` it's because you're running it from a different directory without the `--root` parameter specified. If status returns a line of `Drupal root` but still doesn't give status of database, etc. it's possible that it can't read the settings.php file.